# Con un Boton autoRellenar Formulario

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola buenas necesito metodo autorellenar mi formulario insertare codigo

creo un state en mi provider

```
 const [dat,setDat] =useState({})
```

luego de los datos que muestro necesito hacer editar y autorellenar mi formulario actual lo guardo en la variable setDat

```
{ViewDatos.forEach((employee)=>{
        employee.data.forEach((datos)=>{ 
            resultados.push(
              <>

              <tbody>   
              <tr className="border-b text-center">
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold" >{datos._id}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.fechaInicio}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.fechaTermino}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.fechaPeticion}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.latitudNorte}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.latitudSur}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.longitudOriente}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.longitudPoniente}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.modelType}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.tiempoEstimado}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.requestStatus}</th>
                 <th className="p-4 font-bold">{datos.emergencia}</th>
                 <button onClick={()=>setDat(datos)} className='p-4 font-bold'>Editar</button>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
```

luego en el formulario creo un UseEffect donde paso la variable dat

```
  useEffect(()=>{
  if(dat?._id){
    setDatos(datos.latitudNorte)
  }
    
},[dat])
```

y me sale el siguiente mensaje A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled.
agrego un campo donde quiero recuperar el dato

```
 <div>
                        <label htmlFor="name" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">latitud norte</label>
                        <input type="text" name="latitudNorte" id="latitudNorte" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg  block w-full p-2.5" placeholder="latitudNorte" 
                        value={datos.latitudNorte}
                        onChange={e => handleChangeDatos(e)}
                        
                        />
                    </div>
```

aqui va mi objeto donde tengo el formulario

```
 const  [datos,setDatos] = useState({
        fechaInicio: new Date(Date.UTC()),
        fechaTermino: new Date(Date.UTC()),
        latitudNorte:'',
        latitudSur:'',
        longitudOriente:'',
        longitudPoniente:'',
        emergencia:false
    })
```

Comment: Lee esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro

Comment: lo que pasa es que probe varias soluciones de component is changing a controlled pero no se si estoy haciendo el set de buena manera ..